# Derivative of function f at origin provided 2Ref + 3Imf = 1.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

Let $f = u + iv$ be analytic in a connected open set. If $u$ and $v$ satisfies $2u + 3v = 1$, then what will be the value of $f'(0)$ ? 
Since $f$ is analytic we know it satisfies Cauchy Riemann equation,  also real and imaginary parts will be harmonic. But I couldn't get any conclusion about the function.
Can someone provide an approach to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a proof, but a way to get an insight or check the answer: $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(z)=\frac{i}{3}$ are two such functions $f$, and they both have $f'(0)=0$. So if there's an answer that applies to all such $f$, it must be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $2u+3v=1$, then $2u_x+3v_x=2u_y+3v_y=0$. Now, it is easy to deduce from the Cauchy-Riemann equations that $u$ and $v$ are constant functions. Therefore, $f$ is constant, and so $f'(0)=0$.